# Including a file in CodeIgniter model is causing the server to dump the script on the web page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to develop an application on code igniter framework. My question is when I wrote the model of my application it grew large, so I broke it down into two separate file. The main files merely calls the other one using include command. 
The problem is that the calling file dumps the script in the called file in plain text on the web browser. [image]

my model file looks like this :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Admin_model extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }
    public function return_admin_dashboard_articles($priviledge_id,$by_author=null,$date_published=null){
                $index = 0;
                $query_articles = null;
                //fetching list of articles
                include 'includes/posts_query.inc.php';
                return $data;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

and the file posts_query.inc.php looks like this:

```
<?php>
if($priviledge_id==1 || $priviledge_id==2){

    $this->db->select('articles.id,articles.title,articles.summary,users.user_name,date(articles.pub_date) as 
    pubs_date,articles.author');//add date and time stamp to the table

    $this->db->from('articles');

    $this->db->join('users','articles.author=users.user_id');

    if($by_author and $date_published==null){


        $this->db->where('articles.author',$by_author);

    }

    else if($by_author=='all' and $date_published){

        $this->db->where('date(articles.pub_date)=',$date_published);

    }
    $this->db->where('users.user_priviledge_id=',$priviledge_id); //change this to user_priviledge_id>$priviledge_id to see articles by all the users
    $query_articles = $this->db->get();
}
            //echo $query_articles;
else{
    $this->db->select('articles.id,articles.title,articles.summary,users.user_name,date(articles.pub_date) as pubs_date,articles.author');//add date and time stamp to the table:done
    $this->db->from('articles');
    $this->db->join('users','articles.author=users.user_id');
    $this->db->where('users.user_priviledge_id=',$priviledge_id);
    $query_articles = $this->db->get();
}

if($query_articles->num_rows()>0){
    foreach($query_articles->result_array() as $row){
        $data['articles'][$index]=array(
            'id'=>$row['id'],
            'title'=>$row['title'],
            'summary'=>$row['summary'],
            'author'=>$row['user_name'],
            'date'=>$row['pubs_date'],
            'author_id'=>$row['author']
                        //'time'=>$row['time']
        );
        $index++;
    }     
}
else{
    $data['error']['articles']='Could not fetch articles';
}
?>
```

The complete posts_query.inc.php file is displayed on the web page. What is the reason behind this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

I'm running XAMPP (Apache 2.4.10, PHP 5.6.3,MySql 5.6 CodeIgniter 3.0) on windows 10.

Comment: This is not recomended, put bussiness login into model, don't include other file inside model. Better make another function inside model. If you want to call one function from other use $this->function_name

Comment: The PHP include functionality states that: "When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags." So this is actually the outcome you will get. Also I can't see that you set any data in public function return_admin_dashboard_articles to the $data attribute.

Comment: `return $data;` where is it?The error message says what mistake you did.Try to search with `undefined variable`

Comment: @Martin Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @ShaifulIslam "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward." , This simply means that the variables declared and defined inside the calling function will be available in the called file and you need not explicitly declare a variable $data in the called file in this case. Thank you for the suggestion though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posts_query.inc.php file begins with `<?php>`.
It should be `<?php`. The `>` is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you @IgorGreg this saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I too had this problem moving my code to another server. I was using <? instead of <?php and that also caused the problem.